# How do Malware like Coupon drop down land up in the Windows System without a trace in the Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, malware, windows-defender

I have the Windows Bit Defender updated and run Complete System scans biweekly.

All the drivers and the operating System are up to date.

In spite of this the Coupon drop down malware landed on my Windows 8.1 operating system.

How could this malware/ad-ware land in the Windows operating system and even not leave a trace of it in the Control Panel.

Please suggest measures to avoid such software's in the future and if found how to handle them

**[Update]:-**

I have done the malware threat scan using the given software below and restarted my system.After the restart it gave me a Log file with the following PUP's detected.Now still I am getting the Coupon drop down

Processes: 1

PUP.Optional.Unizeto
Files: 4

PUP.Optional.Unizeto,

PUP.Optional.Somoto,

PUP.Optional.Conduit.A

PUP.Optional.Unizeto

**[Update]:-**
I have repeated the steps thrice for the three sepeate pup's now as the above pup's are removed the 
coupon drop down still persists

Comment: Be carefull what you click when surfing the net and what you install. Many free programs come bundled with adware which in turn may install another malware and so on. If there was a way to keep you 100% safe no matter what you click, there would be no malware in the first place.

Comment: The responsibility of adding itself to the control panel is on the program itself. If malware doesn't want to add itself to the add/remove programs it doesn't have to. That said, malware scanners generally pick up on this.

Answer (score 1):

#### How could this malware install in Windows and appear in the Control?Panel.

It was bundled with some other software you installed.

It may be called something else in the Control Panel (the name of the program it was bundled with) or depending on how it was installed may not have a Control Panel entry at all.

---

#### Please suggest measures to avoid such software's in the future

The full version of [Malwarebytes
Anti-Malware](https://store.malwarebytes.org/342/purl-consumer?x-source=guides&x-action=CouponDropDown) would have protected you against the Coupon Drop Down
hijacker. It would have warned you before the rogue could install
itself, giving you a chance to stop it before it became too late.

> [image]

---

#### Removal instructions for Coupon Drop Down

> **What is Coupon Drop Down?**
>
> The Malwarebytes research team has determined that Coupon Drop Down is a browser hijacker. These so-called "hijackers" manipulate your browser(s), for example to change your startpage or searchscopes, so that the affected browser visits their site or one of their choice. This one also displays advertisements.

...

> **How did Coupon Drop Down get on my computer?**
>
> Browser hijackers use different methods for distributing themselves. This particular one was bundled with other software.
>
> **Is there anything else I need to do to get rid of Coupon Drop Down?**
>
> Coupon Drop Down replaces your hosts file, so you may have to restore the old one. You can find third-party hosts file alternatives at hpHosts or at mvps.org or you can simply reset the default hosts file as outlined here by [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034).
>
> This PUP creates some scheduled tasks. You can read [here](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=85715&view=findpost&p=903065) how to remove Scheduled Tasks.

Source [Removal instructions for Coupon Drop Down](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/165093-removal-instructions-for-coupon-drop-down/)

---

#### I have done the malware threat scan and restarted

> After the restart it gave me a Log file with
> the following PUP's detected, and still I am getting the Coupon drop
> down.

```
Processes: 1
PUP.Optional.Unizeto Files: 4
PUP.Optional.Unizeto,
PUP.Optional.Somoto,
PUP.Optional.Conduit.A
PUP.Optional.Unizeto
```

You have *other* PUPs (Potentially unwanted programs that need to be removed. See the following links for full removal instructions:

- [Remove PUP.Optional.Unizeto virus (Free Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-pup-optional-unizeto-virus/)
- [How to remove Win32/Somoto.G virus (Removal GuideHow to remove Win32/Somoto.G virus (Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/win32-somoto-g-removal/)
- [Remove Conduit Toolbar and search.conduit.com (Uninstall Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-conduit-apps-search-and-toolbar/)

---

#### I have repeated the steps thrice for the three separate pup's now

> as the above pup's are removed the coupon drop down still persists

- [Remove CouponDropDown coupons (Uninstall Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-coupondropdown-coupons/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with MalwareBytes in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: +1 , good clear, unbiased and sensible advice to a question which at first seems very broad yet the answer seems to cover it all.

Comment: Check my Update

Comment: Did you follow the complete removal instructions? See updated answer "Is there anything else I need to do to get rid of Coupon Drop Down?"

Comment: Yes after following the complete removal instructions the log file is generated showing the above four pup's mentioned.I have checked the host file and nothing has been changed in that(the content is same as that to saved as host file)

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Try [Remove CouponDropDown coupons (Uninstall Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-coupondropdown-coupons/)

Comment: @DavidPostill after comparing with the list of softwares in the control panel there exists none matching with the given list.Even now the coupon drown is existing

Comment: Time for a reinstall of your operating system :/